# Outlook 365 update breaks custom task pane

Tags: outlook, office365, vsto, outlook-addin, customtaskpane

We have Outlook add-in that uses VSTO and custom task panes using:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add
```

Latest Outlook updates seem to break custom task panes UI with top position:

[image]

First this issue was reported by one of our clients which used "Try it now" feature of Outlook to see new features. But now it bug slipped to the final release.
We have made a workaround to just add margin for our control and spaces in task pane title, but maybe there is a better way? Pane still look out of place in the new Outlook UI (no rounded corners and so on).
Maybe there is a better way to fix this or some info when this issue will be resolved?

Outlook version is: **Microsoft Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2207 Build 16.0.15427.20182) 64-bit**

Comment: Do you only specify the DockPosition property as msoCTPDockPositionTop? Do yo adjust the position in any way? You might want to open a support case with MS.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yes, only set DockPosition. The code is:
TaskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(_taskPaneControl, "ABCD: Email", _explorer);

TaskPane.VisibleChanged += TaskPaneVisibleChanged;
TaskPane.DockPositionChanged += TaskPaneDockPositionChanged;
TaskPane.DockPosition = MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionTop;

Comment: I have the same problem as you. I applied as well some extra white spaces in front of the title and applied to the ctp content a margin on the left. Anyway when you change screen resolution and/or scale factor from the OS, the title gets slightly shifted to the right, not maintaining its initial position.